# Integral problems for practice

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, contour-integration, spherical-coordinates

Hello can someone give me a few problems with double and triple integral that include polar and not polar form approach and also contour integrals problems, because i am end of examples from textbook and other sources. I want to practice more but i cannot find good examples from google. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try another textbook? There are plenty of calculus textbooks...

Comment: Google demidovich problems

Comment: @Milan Stojanovic Thank you very much.